# Hardware acceleration in Firefox not wokring with AMD integrated GPU

Tags: graphics, firefox, video, amd-graphics

I have run into issues trying to use hardware acceleration for video decoding on Firefox 95.0.1 on Ubuntu 21.10, I am using the package downloaded from apt. I have previously set it up on my old laptop with an intel cpu (I7 7th gen) however I have failed on my new laptop with a AMD 5 5500U CPU (it also has a dedicated RX640 GPU). I tried checking if the acceleration works through radeontop, which suggests it isn't, I also tried the answer in this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370195/enabling-hardware-acceleration-in-firefox) which confirmed it is indeed not working.

I followed the guide on setting this up from the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Hardware_video_acceleration) to no success, I also used the answers to this [post](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/enabling-accelerated-video-decoding-in-firefox-on-ubuntu-21-04/22081/22) and my compositor is now WebRender and not WebRender Software.

Thank you for your help.